# Use getter and setter

Tags: dart

Is is recommended to use in dart getter and setter to define a property like:

```
class Car {
  Engine engine;

  bool get isEngineRunning => engine.isRunning;

  void set isEngineRunning(bool isRunning) {
    engine.isRunning = isRunning;
  }
}
```

And what is advantage of it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do getters and setters change properties in Dart?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683924/how-do-getters-and-setters-change-properties-in-dart)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if it's required because you want to execute some additional code except forwarding to a field.

If the getters and setters are only used to wrap a field, the getters/setters are explicitly discouraged because they are just redundant.

In your case, because you are not forwarding to a field `_isEngineRunning` it's fine if you don't want to expose `Engine engine`.

However because `engine` is public it might be just too much noise and confusing because the same thing can be done in two different ways.

If `engine` would be private it would be better considering https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter