# How do i concatenate two strings where one needs to be a static variable from a Widget in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I have this code from a stateful widget which looks like

```
 static String code = '+1';
 String phone;
 String finalphone = '$code' + '$phone';  =>this declaration brings an error 
 that 'Only static members can be accessed in initializers'
```

How am I supposed to bring the two variables together so that i have something that looks like `+1535465345` i am collecting user information

```
 //the widget

 Widget form() {
  return Form(
  key: _formKey,
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
          letterSpacing: 2.0,
          fontSize: 19.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black87),
      onSaved: (value) => phone = value,               //the (value)  here is a 
                                                       //string which is 
                                                       //assigned 
                                                //to phone variable declared at the top
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

also making the phone variable static and printing out the concatenated string brings out `+1null`

Comment: Where you want to use your `finalphone` variable ?

Comment: it should be used as a sign in for firebase alongside email

Answer (score 6):

You need to specify the class to access static members

```
 String finalphone = '${MyClass.code}$phone';
```

Comment: They are all in one Stateful widget class. Everything in that code is in the same class

Answer (score 6):

Instead of having a `field`, you can have a `getter` like

```
String get finalphone => '$code' + '$phone';
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683924/how-do-getters-and-setters-change-properties-in-dart) answer

Answer (score 2):

sure it will bring an error you use the `phone` variable before give it a value so it will fire null reference exception .
whatever here is a complete fix hope it will work :

```
 static String code = '+1';
 String phone;
 String finalphone = "";

 //the widget

 Widget form() {
  return Form(
  key: _formKey,
    child: TextFormField(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
      ),
      style: TextStyle(
          letterSpacing: 2.0,
          fontSize: 19.0,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          color: Colors.black87),
      onSaved: (value) {phone = value; finalphone = '$code' + '$phone'; }
    ),
  ),
);
```

> you may need to use `setState` to asign value and rebuild the view .