# Custom dropdown widget in Flutter how to implement setState

Tags: flutter, widget

I implemented a custom DropdownButton widget, but I don't know how to implement it's setState. I would like to pass items and selectedItem to the widget, and let it to handle it's own state. And retrieve selected item when needed by myDropdownButton.selectedItem. How I could implement it?

```
class MyDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selected;
  final List<MyDropdownItem> items;

  MyDropdownButton({Key key, this.selected, this.items})
      : super(key: key);

@override
  _MyDropdownButtonState createState() => _MyDropdownButtonState();
}

class _MyDropdownButtonState extends State<MyDropdownButton> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DropdownButtonFormField(
  value: widget.selected,
  onChanged: (String value) {
            widget.selected = value;
            },
```

But the selected is final and cannot be modified. How to implement it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are two questions here:

1. Updating the widget, using setState.
2. Passing the value back to the widget that is using the Dropdown with a callback. [Medium Article on callbacks](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/working-with-callback-in-flutter-89dc207cba37)

Firstly to have the dropdown update, you need to call a setstate on the value change. But first, you'll need to receive the value passed, usually this is done in initstate.

Second, you need to use a callback function. The class that calls this widget/class can then receive and process that value

```
class MyDropdownButton extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selected;
  final List<MyDropdownItem> items;
  
  final Function(String) valueReturned; //callback function

  MyDropdownButton({Key key, this.selected, this.items, this.valueReturned})
      : super(key: key);

@override
  _MyDropdownButtonState createState() => _MyDropdownButtonState();
}

class _MyDropdownButtonState extends State<MyDropdownButton> {
  String sel;
  @override
  void initState() { 
    super.initState();
    sel = widget.selected; //get the value passed
  }
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return DropdownButtonFormField(
  value: sel
  onChanged: (String value) {
    setState() {
            sel = value;
            widget.valueReturned(value); //this will trigger the callback function
            },
      }
```

In the code that calls the widget, you will need to listen to and handle the response.

```
Container(
  child: MyDropdownButton(items: items, selected: selected, valueReturned: _handleValueReturned))

_handleValueReturned(String value) {
    thingToUpdate = value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a local variable and initialize it in initState():

```
String _selected;
```

```
@override
void initState() { 
  super.initState();
  _selected = widget.selected; 
}
```

use setState to update your local variable as the selection changes:

```
onChanged: (String value) {
  setState(() {_selected = value;})
}
```

To retrieve the value, define a getter in your class:

```
String get selectedItem => _selected;
```

You can then access the selected item using `myDropdownButton.selectedItem`.

For more detailed explanation on implicit and explicit getters/setters see [How do getters and setters change properties in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683924/how-do-getters-and-setters-change-properties-in-dart)

Comment: But from parent page I cannot have acces to State class property. Only the property of the class.