# dart/flutter BMI code returns bmi value but other values are wrrong

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    import 'dart:math';

class CalcuatorBrain {
  CalcuatorBrain({this.height, this.weight});

  final int? height;
  final int? weight;

  final double _bmi = 0;

  String calculateBMI() {
    double _bmi = weight! / pow(height! / 100, 2);
   //double _bmi = weight! / (height! * height! ) / 100;
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getResult() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi < 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }

  String getInterpretation() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Try to exercise more.';
    } else if (_bmi >= 18.5) {
      return 'Good job,';
    } else {
      return 'You can eat a bit more.';
    }
  }
}
```

I can't understand what's wrong with my code. The original code works fine (https://github.com/londonappbrewery/BMI-Calculator-Flutter-Completed) but it's outdated, mine has some null checks with "int?" and I also was forced to make:

```
double _bmi = weight! / pow(height! / 100, 2);
```

by adding "!" 2 times.Still I get the same 'Underweight' and 'You can eat a bit more.' but BMI is different. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in code. In `getResult`,

`} else if (_bmi < 18.5) {` needs to be

`} else if (_bmi >= 18.5) {`.

Also prefer non nullable types. I looked the original code, height and weight has default values. So we can make them non-nullable.

`_bmi` should be computed in constructor. Because if `getResult` called before `calculateBMI`, it will return `Underweight` as `_bmi` is `0`. If it is computed in constructor, we can call any method in any order.

```dart
import 'dart:math';

class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({
    required this.height,
    required this.weight,
  }) : _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);

  final int height;
  final int weight;

  final double _bmi;

  String calculateBMI() {
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getResult() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi >= 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }

  String getInterpretation() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Try to exercise more.';
    } else if (_bmi >= 18.5) {
      return 'Good job.';
    } else {
      return 'You can eat a bit more.';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for giving this part:: `_bmi = weight! / pow(height! / 100, 2);` Although I don't know anything about fields and dart required me to make it non-nullable so I used: `: _bmi = weight! / pow(height! / 100, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

Let's examine your code:

```dart
final double _bmi = 0;

String calculateBMI() {
  double _bmi = weight! / pow(height! / 100, 2);
  // double _bmi = weight! / (height! * height! ) / 100;
  return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
}

String getInterpretation() {
  if (_bmi >= 25) {
    return 'Try to exercise more.';
  } else if (_bmi >= 18.5) {
    return 'Good job,';
  } else {
    return 'You can eat a bit more.';
  }
}
```

- The `_bmi` property is always `0`.
- In the `calculateBMI` method a local variable `_bmi` gets calculated which shadows the `_bmi` property.
- The `getInterpretation` method doesn't use the result from the `calculateBMI` method but always uses the final property value.

Let's examine the original code:

```
double _bmi;

String calculateBMI() {
  _bmi = weight / pow(height / 100, 2);
  return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
}

String getInterpretation() {
  if (_bmi >= 25) {
    return 'You have a higher than normal body weight. Try to exercise more.';
  } else if (_bmi >= 18.5) {
    return 'You have a normal body weight. Good job!';
  } else {
    return 'You have a lower than normal body weight. You can eat a bit more.';
  }
}
```

- The `_bmi` property can be modified.
- Besides returning a string representation of the calculated BMI, the `calculateBMI` method updates the `_bmi` property.
- The `getInterpretation` method uses that updated value, if the `calculateBMI` method is called before.

#### Conclusion

As far as I can see, your problem has nothing to do with the update towards non-nullable types. Rather, you should update the property instead of shadowing it with a local variable.

#### References

- [Final and const | dart.dev](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#final-and-const)
- [How do getters and setters change properties in Dart? | stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683924/how-do-getters-and-setters-change-properties-in-dart)
- [Variable shadowing | wikipedia.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing)

Comment: thanks for explaining , but I can't leave double _bmi; as dart says: non0nullable instance field "_bmi" must be initialized.