# SET and GET in dart, Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Could you please explain what do set and get do in the code bellow?

```
class AppScrollBehavior extends MaterialScrollBehavior {

  @override

  Set<PointerDeviceKind> get dragDevices => {

        PointerDeviceKind.touch,
        PointerDeviceKind.mouse,

      };
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do getters and setters change properties in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27683924/how-do-getters-and-setters-change-properties-in-dart)

Comment: `Set` in the above code is the *data structure* named [`Set`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Set-class.html). `get` is used to declare that a method is a property getter.  When `dragDevices` is accessed, it will return a `Set` with elements of type `PointerDeviceKind`.

Answer (score 2):

**`Set`** is one of the Data Types in Dart. A Set is the collection of objects in which each object can occur only once.

According to documentation:-

> *A collection of objects in which each object can occur only once. That is, for each object of the element type, the object is either
> considered to be in the set, or to not be in the set. Set
> implementations may consider some elements indistinguishable. These
> elements are treated as being the same for any operation on the set.
> The default Set implementation, LinkedHashSet, considers objects
> indistinguishable if they are equal with regard to Object.== and
> Object.hashCode.*

More about Set [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Set-class.html)

and **`get`** Getters are special methods that provide read and to an object’s properties.