# How do I use a Firebase timestamp field on the client side?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote a timestamp field to a record. I now want to use it in my Flutter app, but I'm getting this error:

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Timestamp' has no instance method 'getSeconds'.

> Receiver: Instance of 'Timestamp'

> Tried calling: getSeconds()

```
final docRef = firestore.collection(usersCollection).doc(currentUID).collection(friendsCollection).doc('a6b5Ob3TqOYPHOqssype');

final returnData = await docRef.get();
final time = returnData.get('timestamp');
print('##MyApp## database test returnData: ' + time.getSeconds());
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`Timestamp`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/latest/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/Timestamp-class.html) class has no `getSeconds` method.

Instead, use the `seconds` property:

```dart
final time = returnData.get('timestamp');
print('##MyApp## database test returnData: ' + time.seconds);
```

or convert it to a `DateTime`

```dart
final time = returnData.get('timestamp').toDate();
print('##MyApp## database test returnData: ' + time.second);
```

Comment: This worked, but why doesn't the intellisense show `seconds` as an option when I do `time.`?

Comment: Because it doesnt know the type of return value

Answer (score 1):

> NoSuchMethodError: Class 'Timestamp' has no instance method 'getSeconds'.

I assume you are facing this by referring to very old article/code. And now in  `dart`, It is not preferred to use `getters` and `setters` as it uses **implicitly**.

To back my point.

Refer [pixels elephant's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27691564/13431819)

> Instance variables in Dart have implicit getters and setters. So for your example code, it will operate in exactly the same way, since all you have done is changed from an implicit getter and setter to an explicit getter and setter.

---

1. To solve the error use `seconds` instead of `getSeconds()`

   - So now when you call `time.seconds` internally it is calling

     ```
     int get seconds => _seconds;
     ```
2. This worked, but why doesn't the intellisense show `seconds` as an option when I do `time` ?

   Try defining the type:

   ```
   DateTime time = returnData.get('timestamp').toDate();
   print('##MyApp## database test returnData: ' + time.second);
   ```